# How to decrease the timeout of a TcpOutboundGateway?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tcp, spring-integration

I have noticed that whenever I send a request on a `TcpOutboundGateway` configured to connect to a Host/Port that does not exist/is unavailable, the processing of the request will hang for 1 minute and 15 seconds before throwing the following exception…

`java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)`

I am hoping to reduce that 1 minute and 15 second wait time but have not been able to find the correct way to do so. Up to this point I have tried setting the remoteTimeout, requestTimeout and sendTimeout on the `TcpOutboundGateway` and none of those seem to do the trick.

Is it possible to configure the `TcpOutboundGateway` in way that will reduce the amount of time it waits before throwing that exception? If possible, how so?

***Note:*** In regards to “a Host/Port that does not exist”, an example of this would be running my application locally with the TcpOutboundGateway configured to send to 127.0.0.3:2000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection problem is not a gateway responsibility. It is really about a `ConnectionFactory`.

See `AbstractClientConnectionFactory`:

```
/**
 * Set the connection timeout in seconds. Defaults to 60.
 * @param connectTimeout the timeout.
 * @since 5.2
 */
public void setConnectTimeout(int connectTimeout) {
```

Althoug, I see that this one might not be available for you since we are going yet to release `5.2` only the next week.

For the current `5.1.x` version you need to extend a `TcpNetClientConnectionFactory` and its `createSocket()` to provide an appropriate connection timeout:

```
public class MyTcpNetClientConnectionFactory extends TcpNetClientConnectionFactory {

    protected Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException {
        Socket socket = getTcpSocketFactorySupport().getSocketFactory().createSocket();
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), 1000);
        return socket;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the response Artem. I believe your createSocket override solution will do the trick for now. I will keep an eye out for the release of setConnectionTimeout method in the near future.